# Find closest comparables using R

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to find the closest comparable real estate sales to a subject property using R.  I need the output to include the distance between the different variables.

I've tried using the `dist` function, but it produces an output comparing all rows in a matrix to each other.  Ideally I want to compare a single subject to a list of sales with the output ordered by the closest match with the distance of each variable listed.

example data;

**sales**

```
parcel  square_feet age quality 

R100          2500   10       4
R200          1800   15       3
R300          2200    8       5
```

**subject**

```
R400          1900   14       4
```

Ideally I would like output something like this

```
parcel  sq_ft_dist age_dist  qual_dist

R200          100    1       1
R300          300    6       1
R100          600    4       0
```

**Edit**
I am looking for the Euclidean distance between the parcels.

**Edit2** 
To clarify my question, I can get the Euclidean distance between each row using the `dist` function. It returns a value for each pair in a matrix.  Thats great but it's more than what I need and the output matrix can grow very large for big data sets.  I only need the distance between the subject and the other rows.  I suppose I can just pull the distances I'm interested in from the output of `dist`, then manually calculate the distance between the variables. I was asking in the hopes there is an R function that already does this.

Comment: You appear to have three distances (square footage, age, and quality). How are you combining those three distances when you're ordering?

Comment: Yeah, you can't sort by "closest" until/unless you define it.

Comment: Sorry, I mean Euclidian distance metric, like dist() uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it would help someone else, I found a function that does exactly what I was looking for, `dist2` from the `flexclust` package. 
It calculates the distance the same way as `dist` but instead of pairing every observation in a single matrix, you give it a second vector or matrix to compare the first to.
Read about it [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/flexclust/docs/dist2).

Answer (score 2):

I think statistical matching will be helpful for this task. Maybe Mahalanobis distance or propensity score matching. This would help you avoid the issue pointed out by commenters that you'll have to find a way to combine your three Euclidian distances. Check out the package MatchIt:

http://r.iq.harvard.edu/docs/matchit/2.4-20/matchit.pdf

Sorry for the pseudo-answer; I don't have enough rep to comment :/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `dplyr` can come to your assistance.  I added your parcel R400 as the last entry in the data frame (df)

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  group_by(parcel) %>%
  summarise(sqftdist = df[4,2]-square_feet, 
            agedist =  df[4,3]-age, 
            qualdist = df[4,4]-quality)

> df
Source: local data frame [4 x 4]

  parcel sqftdist agedist qualdist
1   R100    -1100       4        0
2   R200     -400      -1        1
3   R300     -800       6       -1
4   R400        0       0        0
```

Here was the data frame:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(parcel = structure(1:4, .Label = c("R100", "R200", 
"R300", "R400"), class = "factor"), sqftdist = c(-1100L, -400L, 
-800L, 0L), agedist = c(4L, -1L, 6L, 0L), qualdist = c(0L, 1L, 
-1L, 0L)), .Names = c("parcel", "sqftdist", "agedist", "qualdist"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), drop = TRUE)
```